# Pandas running sum

Tags: pandas, syntax, cumsum

I have a pandas dataframe and it is something like this:

```
 x y
 1 0
 2 1
 3 2
 4 0 <<<< Reset
 5 1
 6 2
 7 3
 8 0 <<<< Reset
 9 1
10 2
```

The `x` values could be anything, they are not meaningful for this question. The y values increment, and reset and increment again. I need a third column `(z)` which is a number that represents the groups, so it increments when the y values are reset.

I cannot guarantee that the reset will be to zero, only a value that is less than the previous one, should indicate a reset.

```
 x y z
 1 0 0
 2 1 0
 3 2 0
 4 0 1 <<<< Incremented by 1
 5 1 1
 6 2 1
 7 3 1
 8 0 2 <<<< Incremented by 1
 9 1 2
10 2 2
```

So To produce `z`, i understand what needs to be done, just not familiar with the syntax. My solution would be to first assign `z` as a sparse column of 0 and 1's, where everything is zero except a 1 is given when `y[ix] < y[ix-1]`, indicating that the `y` counter has been reset. Then a cumulative running sum should be performed on the `z` column, meaning that: `z[ix] = sum(z[0],z[1],...,z[ix])`

Id appreciate some help with the syntax of assigning column z, if someone has a moment.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your logic:

```
#general case
df['z'] = df['y'].diff().lt(0).cumsum()

# or equivalently
# df['z'] = df['y'].lt(df['y'].shift()).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
    x  y  z
0   1  0  0
1   2  1  0
2   3  2  0
3   4  0  1
4   5  1  1
5   6  2  1
6   7  3  1
7   8  0  2
8   9  1  2
9  10  2  2
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `ne(1)`

```
df.y.diff().ne(1).cumsum().sub(1)
```

---

```
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    1
7    2
8    2
9    2
Name: y, dtype: int32
```